# what is the best way of making a filter pre every page in vaadin

Tags: spring-boot, filter, vaadin

hi i wanna have a filter pre every web pages that check someting and if that thing was incorrect show me an error page
and if it was fine just show me the page

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vaadin is mostly based on individual interactions such as clicking buttons or scrolling in a grid, rather than viewing pages. What you can still do is to use `UI::addBeforeEnterListener` to get an event before navigating to a new target. You can use a `VaadinServiceInitListener` to register that listener for all your UI instances.

For more information, have a look at [this blog](https://vaadin.com/blog/the-dangers-of-using-the-wrong-abstraction-for-vaadin-access-control) post that I've written on the topic.